# Multi purpose IO solution with FPGA

Tags: io, fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga, adc

I've to design an IO-module for an industrial control system in a CAN-bus network.

The IO-pins (10-40 pins) have to be all multi purpose: digital and analog in- and output. Further the pins have to serve as a communication port when needed: Modbus RTU, modbus TCP, DALI, etc. (Analog input max 7 channels)

I understand that all of this options need different HW; like galvanic isolation or different voltage levels etc.

Costs have to be as low as possible.

I was thinking of making this bit of additional hardware as a plug-in module or as an optional additional sandwich PCB.

My question is: Is an FPGA the right choice for this because of the reconfigurable purpose of the IO-pins? (Xilinx, altera/intel and microsemi have FPGA's with ADC's)

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) provides guidance on a lot of useful topics as well as offering the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if IOs have to be reconfigurable at compile or runtime. In most cases, you cannot change IO properties (type, voltage, terminations,etc.) once HDL code is compiled into FPGA bitstream.

Comment: I didn't specify it because it does not matter in my case. code can be compiled for different purposes.